# Sudo: How can I exlude one specific command line argument from sudo

Tags: sudo

There is a command (say: mycommand) that we want to add to sudo for all users, but there is one specific command line option -i that we want to exclude. Complicating factor is that command line arguments can be combined, making it harder to build a regex or something. So we want to allow:

- sudo mycommand
- sudo mycommand -p -f something -w
- sudo mycommand -pf something -w

but not:

- sudo mycommand -**i**
- sudo mycommand -p -**i** -f something -w
- sudo mycommand -p**i**f something -w

So far I have had mixed results, like incorrectly allowing "sudo mycommand -piw" or incorrectly blocking "sudo mycommand -pf someth**i**ng -w"

Any suggestions, other than writing a wrapper script?

Comment: the question is imho too generic. please specify what kind of command is used

Comment: @djdomi - I  don't see how that is relevant, but the command is /usr/sbin/swlist

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to exclude command line options using patterns in the sudoers file.  However, this can be error prone so a wrapper script is often a better approach.

If you are using sudo 1.9.10 or higher, you can use regular expressions in the sudoers file, which allows you to do things like:

```
someuser ALL = /usr/bin/swlist, !/usr/bin/swlist ^.*-i.*$
```

which would reject any command line arguments that include '-i'.  However, if the command supports compound options this won't catch things like:

```
$ sudo swlist -pi -f something -w
```

In that (likely) case, you'll need something like:

```
someuser ALL = /usr/bin/swlist, !/usr/bin/swlist ^.*-[^[:space:]]*i.*$
```

Older versions of sudo only support shell-style globing patterns which are more limited and don't support what you want to do.

Comment: That answer looks promising, but unfortunately I'm stuck with sudo 1.8.6, without possibility of upgrading due to "corporate rules". 
Big thanks anyway.